# PHP - How can i put break line between if value are not the same from sql

Tags: php, sql, line-breaks

for example:

```
-------------------------
| ID  | Date | Name |
-------------------------
| 1  | 2018-01-03 | Name 1 |
| 2  | 2018-01-03 | Name 2 |
| 3  | 2018-01-04 | Name 3 |
```

I want Output like this:

```
Name 1<br>
Name 2<br>
<br>
Name 3
```

Comment: you mean you want a line break when the date changes?

Comment: Can you show us your PHP code?

Comment: Barmar that's what i want . i need to put break line when date change . i need this in retrieving record from database

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the links . i already got what i actually want :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? Output fields according to different values? If so, you can do this：

```
select name from table group by date
```